# 4 channel digital scope

Tags: ac, oscilloscope, mains, alternator

I wish to view 3 phase waveforms from an alternator (DUT) through isolation transformers via a digital oscilloscope. A 4 channel oscilloscope is obviously ideal for this as I can view the waveforms as they occur 'simultaneously' and the frequency is very low, but can this be done any way on a 2 channel scope?
I think the only way is to save each waveform them view them on at once.

Thanks

Comment: The 2nd question should be removed ( to another) and mains voltage given with attention to arc flash safety codes reading as a prerequisite.  The 1st Q. depends if your scope can view trigger signal. Otherwise probe trigger off A and also View from CH1  adjust scales then view B,C only on CH1,2 with trigger on A

Comment: What's the purpose of "viewing"? The 3 phases are mutually dependent, so a third phase can be derived mathematically from the other two. So if your scope has the "Math" channel, it might have the required operations (not sure about modern scopes, but the older ones had some simple operations only)..

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is only valid if an alternator is healthy. I need to see how the alternator terminal voltage amplitude changes with load(s), so for unbalanced loads each phase waveform may be different.

Comment: @David777 That's why I asked about the purpose

Comment: You wouldn't want to save the waveforms, but rather view them in successive pairs and make a value judgement.  Frequency is likely to be low enough that you could use some random ADC as your "scope".  However, unless you have AC loads that bypass the regulator, you really shouldn't need to do this.  If you suspect a winding or the regulators, then you should just be able to load it (turn on the headlights?) and look at each phase in turn.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry Eugene, I will explain better. For a project I'm making a 3 phase generator basic control system using an alternator with a prime mover and automatic voltage regulation. I need to measure voltages/phase angles under no load and various loads to see how the terminal voltage changes and how fast it is compensated for when loads are connected AND disconnected etc. I think this will provide more information than using an RMS multimeter, but would rather view all 3 phases on one scope.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ,  Chris, I'm using an alternator to produce 3 phase which is not in a vehicle so there is no rectification or regulator. I'm trying to create a 3 phase generator that COULD theoretically be used to power AC loads, balanced or unbalanced with frequency control & over/under voltage control (note; only for a project, not going to be used).

Comment: You could buy a DS1054Z.  But you could probably also do with an MCU and some care in sampling three ADC channels at a fast regular interval and uplinking the data to a PC.  Of course you'll need some care to input circuit, too.  **The thing is you'll probably learn less from seeing all three at once than you think** - but up to you to decide if that is worth $375 or a long day of improvising to see that for yourself.  And in the end neither the money or the time will be wasted, because the tool or experience will have lasting value.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, a microcontroller based circuit is my end goal but for the sake of the project, I need to show real visual representation of the voltages. I think I am going to buy an oscilloscope anyway, so if a 4 channel would greatly benefit me for this project I would get the Rigol DS1054Z, otherwise a new Tektronix 2 channel is around the same prize and would get it instead. Anyway, I will always have the scope and they do come in handy.

Comment: I meant you could use an MCU as the front end of a scope and a PC as the display

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ah right, no I would rather by a proper oscilloscope but I'm unsure whether a 4 channel scope would benefit me more than a 2 channel scope for this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't view all three at once with a two channel oscilloscope. However, you could trigger on 1, capture 1 + 2 and save #2. Then, use the same trigger but capture 1 + 3 and you could compare them all.

This will only work if it's repeatable, though. If you have 1-off signals that change every cycle or look different every time you'll need a 4-channel scope.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I’m going for a 4 channel oscilloscope as I would like to see all 3 signals change instaneously